# RAID disk size is less than display in SSA on HP Proliant DL380 Gen10

Tags: grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I set up RAID1+0 with 8 1TB SATA HDDs by SSA(Smart Storage Administrator).
I confirmed 4TB disk was made in SSA but after installing Ubuntu16.04, I could see only 1.8TB disk size by both parted command and dmesg.
I use HPE Smart Array P816i-a as RAID controller.

GPT pertition is used for over 2.2TB disk size.

/dev/sda1 efi
/dev/sda2 ext4 /
/dev/sda3 swap

The result of lsblk is as follows.

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 sda      8:0    1   1.7T  0 disk
   sda1   8:1    1 513.1M  0 part /boot/efi
   sda2   8:2    1   1.6T  0 part /
   sda3   8:3    1  63.7G  0 part [SWAP]
 sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Do you have any idea to use full disk size?

Comment: Please include the output of `sudo lsblk`

Comment: I reflected your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved.
As follows, to be exact HP ProLiant DL380 Gen10 supports Ubuntu 16.04.**3** (HWE Kernel 4.10).
http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/exceptions/ubuntu_exceptions.aspx
After re-installing it, disk is recognized correctly.